# Sklearn Confusion Matrix: Change colobar

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I think the answer should be super simple, but I'm not finding an immediate solution to the problem. I have a confusion matrix, and I'd like to change colors to just blue colors (grade type).

Is it possible to do this in a simple way, using "colobar"?

plot_confusion_matrix(clf_LR9, X1_test, y1_test)

[image]

Tks in advance

Comment: According to the documentation there is a cmap parameter. Try that: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

Comment: Perfect. I didn't notice this parameter, i was fixed in colorlab. My bad. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `cmap` parameter to `"Blues"`.

```
plot_confusion_matrix(clf_LR9, X1_test, y1_test, cmap="Blues")
```